# Universal path to chrome.exe

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am making an application and I want to make it installable on the user's desktops using chrome URL shortcut. Therefore, is there a universal path to the chrome.exe that can launch my app on all Windows versions ( XP, Seven and vista )

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384893/how-do-i-use-c-sharp-to-get-the-path-to-chrome-exe-on-windows/45384927#45384927

Answer (score 38):

Chrome installs by default to the User's AppData Local folder:

```
XP:

C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome

Vista:

C:\Users\UserName\AppDataLocal\Google\Chrome

Windows 7:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Application

Win 7/8/10/11, (either):

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
- C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
```

Best bet is to use some OS detection code, then use an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) to detect the User's `AppData` folder (i.e. `%LOCALAPPDATA%`) or the `ProgramFiles` folder, and then append the difference in OS's to the end of the variable.

Comment: MIght i recommend that if you need to support the older systems, `C:\Users\%UserName%\AppDataLocal\Google\Chrome` is the percent signs around the username. Then it will pass in who is logged into that box.

Comment: Google has changed that. Now Chrome installs into the Programs folder as it should have done from the first day.

Comment: How can I know in which directory chrome was installed in (`Program Files (x86)\...` or `Program Files\...`)?

Comment: @MahmoudMousaHamadAs of today's date (since Google likes to play whack-a-mole with us), what I would probably do is first fetch the `ProgramFiles` Environment Variable, and append `\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` to it, test that the file exists, and if not, do the same with the `ProgramFiles(x86)` environment variable. If it's installed, it should find it at one of the 2 places.

Answer (score 38):

You can look in the Registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe
```

Comment: I didn't have an entry here. But I did search the registry for "chrome.exe" and it came right up. Mine is in Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe for Windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

The registry option might be the best, but the one suggested in the other answer didn't exist in my computer (Windows 10 64-bit). I think the "Uninstall" key might be more robust. If it didn't exist, users would have a hard time uninstalling Chrome. The following keys give you the install location, you'll need to append `"\chrome.exe"` to get the full path to the executable:

**Chrome:**

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome\InstallLocation
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome\InstallLocation
```

**Chrome Canary:**

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome SxS\InstallLocation

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome SxS\InstallLocation
```

Comment: I have Chrome installed on my computer, but I don't see it listed at this location.  Running Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: @zumalifeguard I edited the answer, try with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. If you don't find it there, open Regedit and try to look for the string "chrome.exe" repeatedly pressing F3 until you find the Uninstall key. And please share with us.

Comment: JL, Take a look at the logic that Karam's chrome-launcher uses to locate chrome.  https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/blob/master/index.js   It's fairly robust.     The other place I thought would be useful is `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command` you can parse out the exe in there as well.

Comment: @zumalifeguard in my computer the path you mentioned doesn't exist, because a bunch of letters and numbers is appended to 'ChromeHTML': `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML.<ProgId>\shell\open\command`. Does HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome\InstallLocation exist in your computer?

Answer (score 4):

**Win 7 32 bit**:

`c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

**Win 7 64 bit** (*or W10 64b*):

`c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

*(which is different from the preceding answers and comments)*.

Clay Nichols [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25786056/553663) to look in the registry is of course recommended.

*Please do not edit!*

*Someone "edited" this answer saying 32 bit paths are always `(x86)`, showing a total misunderstanding of the question and the answer! The path `c:\Program Files (x86)\` does not even exist on a 32 bit machine (unless you manually add it youself); both of the above are tested answers*.

Comment: 2022 Win 10 64bit `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

Comment: @TwoFingerRightClick - not on my 2022 Win 10 64bit. Have you tried it? Anyway, Chrome is still 32 bit unless you have a Beta of a 64b version.

Comment: Hmm. Chrome has been built 64 bit for a good while now (since chrome 37 according to this article : https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/08/chrome-64-bit-browser-finally-available-as-a-stable-version/). So new installs will be installed in `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application` One can check if version is 64 bit as in about chrome it will have a `(64 bit)` at the end of the version. Maybe you are thinking of Chrome Android which is more recently released in 64 bit.

Comment: Perhaps people have been using Chrome so long, that they never did a new install of it and so still have the 32 bit version? Or maybe Chrome just keeps using the same directory that it was originally installed in back in the day when it was 32-bit?

Comment: I found an article that answers those questions, and it was that google just kept using the x86 folder untill 2020 even though chrome is 64 bit since 2014 : https://techdows.com/2020/06/64-bit-chrome-install-program-files-windows.html

Answer (score 2):

For Windows users `chrome.exe` could have been be installed in several places based on the user's Window's edition (64 or 32-bit) and when the user installed Chrome it:

#### Current Locations

It'll most likely be in either:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`

  - For 32-bit Chrome
  - Or 64-bit edition if you *installed Chrome before 2020. See: [Windows Chrome 64-bit prepared to install into Program Files](https://techdows.com/2020/06/64-bit-chrome-install-program-files-windows.html)
- `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application`

  - for Chrome 64-bit edition *(the default install location since 2020)
- `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application`

  - For 32 bit Chrome on Windows 32-bit ([`Program Files (x86)` is used only on windows 64-bit to denote 32-bit applications](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/program-files-x86#:%7E:text=The%20regular%20Program%20Files%20folder,to%20Program%20Files%20(x86).))

*Much confusion is caused by the fact that Chrome has been 64 bit since 2014, but Google still used `Program Files (x86)` until 2020 as the install location. And if you installed Chrome before 2020 then it will [continue to live in the `Program Files (x86)` directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/2001eb11359fae01107202c73ffb657f0d918d70):

```
Browsers installed under "C:\Program Files (x86)" remain in that
directory and will continue to be updated. They must be uninstalled
first to be reinstalled under "C:\Program Files".
```

#### Legacy Locations

Chrome used to install to the user folder for Vista and XP:

```
XP:
C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome

Vista:
C:\Users\UserName\AppDataLocal\Google\Chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking out for mac and this is how I found:

**1. Using Finder:**
Open Finder.
Navigate to the Applications folder.
Find Google Chrome.
Right-click on Google Chrome and select "Get Info."
In the "General" section of the info window, you'll see "Where:" which shows the path to the application. By default, it should be /Applications/Google Chrome.app.

**2. Using mdfind Command in Terminal:**
Open Terminal.

Run the following command:

`mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == 'Google Chrome' && kMDItemKind == 'Application'"`

---

Using the first point I checked and verified using command mentioned in second point.

The path to the Google Chrome application is typically /Applications/Google Chrome.app if not manually installed in some other path.

Answer (score -1):

I had a `.mht` file that I would like to open in chrome, and found that just running:

```
chrome.exe "path-to-file.mht"
```

would work just fine! No need to find the path :)

Comment: It is not certain that the path to _chrome.exe_ will be saved in system _PATH_ variable :(