# How do I use C# to get the path to chrome.exe on Windows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome

I want to launch chrome from my automated test framework so that I can test my server-side ASP.NET code.  What's the best way to determine the location of where chrome.exe is located on my computer?

Comment: Even though you answered your own question (perfectly fine) via some good answers, one could argue that your question itself is _too broad_ and _"best way"_ is subject to opinion.  Ignoring your answers, your question shows no sign of research.  Any code to show?  [ask]

Answer (score 12):

When Chrome is installed on a computer, it installs the `ChromeHTML` URL protocol.   You could use that to get to the path for Chrome.exe.

Some example code may help.  The following code returns a string that looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1"
```

Example code to get that:

```
var path = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(
    @"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command", null, null) as string;
if (path != null)
{
    var split = path.Split('\"');
    path = split.Length >= 2 ? split[1] : null;
}
```

if path is null at the end of the code snippet, then you can assume Chrome isn't installed.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is use the logic used by the Karma test framework.

```
const string suffix = @"Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
var prefixes = new List<string> {Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)};
var programFiles = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
var programFilesx86 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
if (programFilesx86 != programFiles)
{
    prefixes.Add(programFiles);
}
else
{
    var programFilesDirFromReg = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion", "ProgramW6432Dir", null) as string;
    if (programFilesDirFromReg != null) prefixes.Add(programFilesDirFromReg);
}

prefixes.Add(programFilesx86);
var path = prefixes.Distinct().Select(prefix => Path.Combine(prefix, suffix)).FirstOrDefault(File.Exists);
```

if path is null at the end of the code snippet, then you can assume Chrome isn't installed.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it assumes that the mere presence of Chrome in one of the folders implies that it is _installed correctly_ which it may not (it may be sans _registry_ entries with orphaned files in the file system).   That's why registry approach (as per your answer below) works better

Comment: Micky, I think that assuming that Chrome is installed correctly is an acceptable compromise that most people would be willing to live with.   Thanks for your feeback.