# Python Selenium Chrome Get default download path

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

How do I get the default "Downloads" path on Selenium using python and chromedriver?
I saw a lot of questions/answers to set the "Downloads" path to a specific folder but nothing about identifying the default folder to which "Downloads" are being saved to.
I use Windows, but ideally would like an answer compatible for any systems.
Thanks
I was hoping to find it in the debugging of chromedrive objet, but the information I found is as followed:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a link inside of stack overflow doing the same aspect you are looking for. You would just have to program it for your end along with testing exceptions. Not everyone has chrome so expectations would be necessary.

**[Universal path to chrome.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736215/universal-path-to-chrome-exe)**

Comment: tx. I am not after the chrome.exe path, but the default download folder: where files get downloaded when you click a save button. best